# Mistake in number of ways in which we can assign $7$ projects to $4$ people such that each person get at least one project

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Number of ways in which we can assign $7$ projects to $4$ people such that each person get at least one project:

**My approach to this question was:**

First assign $1$ project to everyone.

For this I first choose $4$ jobs out of $7$ and count every way i.e.$\binom{7}{4}4!$.

Next thing I did was applying the combinations with replacement as

J # J # J #

J J J # # #

J # # # J J

.

.

.

where 2 # are kind of boundaries and 3rd is also a boundary which also covers one position.

(Sorry but I don't remember the formula and always use it like this)

I got the solution $\binom{6}{3}$.

Now I thought I got all the cases and by product rule
$$\binom{7}{4}4!\binom{6}{3}$$

would give me answer. But the answer that I got was $16800$ while the answer in my book is $8400$. So where did I go wrong and why do I have to divide with $2$?

Comment: To obtain $\binom{n}{k}$, type `$\binom{n}{k}$`.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks, didn't know that!

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: The formula you are using to obtain $\binom{6}{3}$ is $\binom{n - 1}{k - 1}$, which is the number of solutions of the equation $$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n$$ in the positive integers.  See [Theorem 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By designating particular projects as the one received by each person and then distributing the remaining projects, you count the same distribution multiple times.  However, you made a second mistake.  You forgot to choose which which additional project is received by which person.  Had you done that, you would have had a much larger answer:

Since $7$ can be partitioned into four parts in three ways:
\begin{align*}
7 & = 4 + 1 + 1 + 1\\
  & = 3 + 2 + 1 + 1\\
  & = 2 + 2 + 2 + 1
\end{align*}
either one person receives four projects and each of the other people receives a single project; one person receives three projects, a second person receives two projects, and each of the other two people receives a single project; or three people each receive two projects and the other person receives one.

*One person receives four projects and each of the others receives a single project*:  Choose which of the four people receives four projects, choose which four of the seven projects that person receives, then distribute the remaining three projects to the remaining three people so that each person receives one.  This can be done in
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{7}{4}3!$$
ways.

*One person receives three projects, a second person receives two projects, and each of the others receives a single project*:  Choose which person receives three projects, choose which three of the seven projects that person receives, choose which of the remaining three people receives two projects, choose which two of the remaining four projects that person receives, then distribute the remaining two projects to the remaining two people so that each person receives one.  This can be done in
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{7}{3}\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{2}2!$$
ways.

*Three people each receive two projects and the remaining person receives one*:  Choose which three of the four people each receive two projects, choose which two of the seven projects the most senior of these three people receives, choose which
two of the remaining five projects the next most senior of these three people receives, choose which two of the remaining three projects the least senior of these three people receives, then give the remaining project to the remaining person.  This can be done in
$$\binom{4}{3}\binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}\binom{1}{1}$$
ways.

**Total:**  The number of ways the seven projects can be distributed to four people so that each person receives at least one project is
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{7}{4}3! + \binom{4}{1}\binom{7}{3}\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{2}2! + \binom{4}{3}\binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}\binom{1}{1} = 8400$$

Had you remembered to choose which person receives which additional project, you would have found that there were
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{3} + \binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{3}{1}\binom{1}{1} + \binom{4}{3}3! = 64$$
such distributions, which would have given you the incorrect total
$$\color{red}{\binom{7}{4}4!\left[\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{3} + \binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{3}{1}\binom{1}{1} + \binom{4}{3}3!\right] = 53,760}$$

Your method counts each case in which a person receives four projects and each of the others receives one four times, once for each way of designating one of the four projects the person who receives four projects as the project that person receives.

Your method counts each case in which a person receives three projects, a second person receives two projects, and each of the others receives a single project six times, once for each way of designating one of three projects the person who receives three projects as the project that person receives and once for each way of designating one of the two projects the person who receives two projects receives as the project that person receives.

Your method counts each case in which three people each receive two projects and the other person receives one eight times, once for each of the two ways you could designate one of the two projects each of three people who receives two projects as the project that person receives.

Notice that
$$\color{red}{4} \cdot \binom{4}{1}\binom{7}{4}3! + \color{red}{3 \cdot 2} \cdot \binom{4}{1}\binom{7}{3}\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{2}2! + \color{red}{2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2} \cdot \binom{4}{3}\binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}\binom{1}{1} = \color{red}{53,760}$$

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is number of surjective mappings between set of project to set of people(functions onto). There is formula for it:
$$ m!S(n,m)$$
Where :

1. S(n,m) is stirling number of second kind
2. n,m are numbers of elements in domain and codomain

4!S(7,4) = 8400

Comment: I'll look into the surjective mapping. Thanks! But can you please tell me where did I go wrong. I would like to know the mistakes in my approach also.

Comment: @UtkarshSharma you treat projects as undistinguished  elements - what was not  desired by creator of exercise. If they were undistinguished your approach is correct.